# C++ in Unity with dependencies

Tags: unity, c++

I am currently creating a c++ program to eventually use in Unity. This c++ program contains references to libraries like OpenCV and dlib, referenced with a include statement which calls in other files, which are installed on my machine. My question is:

How do you compile your c++ project so that it runs in Unity completely self-contained? i.e no reference to external files are needed, and all that are references are included within the program. Is there a specific tool to use, or a useful tutorial on the net?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Unity is able to call functions from dynamically linked libraries using the [plugin system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html). When you are using C++, then you are dealing with a [native plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html). Keep in mind that native plugins are not platform-independent. So if you want to publish your game for multiple platforms, you also need to manually build your library in formats which work for these platforms.

Regarding adding files to your library: Microsoft Visual Studio can pack files into a compiled Windows DLL in form of "[resources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio)". I am not familiar enough with library development on other operating systems to tell if there are equivalent mechanisms.

However, if you designed your program as a stand-alone executable, then turning it into a library might require some refactoring. If you would prefer to avoid that, then there is another option: Run both your Unity game and your C++ program as separate processes and have them communicate through network messages. Check the documentation of the [Unity Transport Layer API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingTransport.html) for details.